# Describing surfaces

Tags: calculus

I'm working on a problem that deals with describing surfaces given specific information (we're studying rectangular, cylindrical, cartesian, spherical coordinates). I am posed with the question:

Describe the surface whose equation is given by $\rho$ = 3, and $\theta$ = $\pi$/4.

Now, I know that spherical coordinates use ($\rho$, $\theta$, $\phi$) positioning, so this is a therefore in spherical coordinates.

Thus, we are given the $\theta$ as the angle in the xy-plane, and the $\rho$ as the distance between P and the origin. However, I can't conceptualize this concept without being given a $\phi$. How does the P and Q (Q here being the ending point of our line determined by $\theta$ in our xy-plane) connect up to each other without $\phi$? won't the tip of P be on the z-axis?

Comment: You must think of ALL the points in space having $\rho=3$, $\theta=\pi/4$ and any $\phi$.

Comment: Let $\phi$ go from 0 to $2\pi$. Are you sure $\theta$ is in the xy plane?

Comment: @JohnDouma $\phi$ usually goes only from $0$ to $\pi$, not to $2\pi$

Comment: @coldnumber I believe $\phi$ is the angle in the xy plane in sperical coordinates. $\theta$ is not the same as it is in cylindrical coordinates.

Comment: @JohnDouma OP writes in the question that $\theta$ is the angle in the $xy$-plane. Also, see here:http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalCoordinates.html

Comment: That may be, but https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system shows it the other way as do many calculus books. This surface is part of a cone.

Comment: @JohnDouma It doesn't matter what other books do because OP told us what theirs does; the context is in the question, and in the question there is no ambiguity about the meaning of $\theta$ or $\phi$.

Comment: What if he got it wrong? Why would his professor ask for a surface if the answer was a semicircle?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26395/discussion-between-coldnumber-and-john-douma).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In space, fix $\rho=3$ and $\theta = \dfrac \pi4$, and now let $\phi$ go from $0$ to $\pi$ (the fact that  $\phi$ is not mentioned in the equation means it can have any value). Graph a few points, maybe at $\phi=0,\pi/4,\pi/3,\pi/2,$ etc. What curve do you get?

A side note: A good way to get better at visualizing spherical coordinates is to play around with this applet: http://www.math.uri.edu/~bkaskosz/flashmo/tools/sphcoords/

Comment: it seems to be a semi-circle on the z-axis at a 45 degree and in quadrant one of the XY-plane. Is that right, or am I still missing something?

Comment: That sounds right (remember to give the radius).

Comment: Excellent, thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome :)

Comment: but I think the answer must be a curve and not a surface. it's the intersection of the sphere $\rho=3$ and the plane $\theta=\frac{\pi}{4}$.

Comment: @sepideh and I agree, but my professor said in the question "describe the surface...", so I'll just go with what he said and mention it after class. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, semi-circles are curves, not surfaces. @Sepideh I'll fix that in my answer, thanks.

Comment: @coldnumber it's not a semi-circle its the great circle of the sphere which passes through the z-axis and makes angle $\frac{\pi}{4}$ with $zy$ or $zx$ plane.I think you have supposed $\rho$ be a positive number but it can be any number.look at the shape of this problem

Comment: @sepideh I don't see why. The angle $\pi/4$ is measured from the $x$-axis counterclockwise on the $xy$-plane; and $\rho$ is fixed at 3.

Comment: because $\theta=\frac{\pi}{4}$ is the equation of the $y=x$ line in the xy-plane. this line will be in both quadrant 1 and quadrant 4. in the previous comment I made a mistake $\rho$ is always positive.but that does not change the answer of the problem.the answer is the great circle

Comment: @sepideh In Stewart, $\theta= \pi/4$ is actually a half-plane

Comment: in Stewart! well that's the notation of a book. We study tomas calculus in university and there's no such convention there. In general case $\theta=\frac{\pi}{4}$ should be a plane.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26366/discussion-between-coldnumber-and-sepideh).

Comment: See figure 15.48 in Thomas 12th ed. It's a half plane.

Comment: When I learned sperical coordinates, $\theta$ is not the same angle as it is in cylindrical coordinates. I believe your surface is a cone.